# DOB field in magento newsletter subcription

Tags: magento, html5-canvas, magento-1.7, date

I need to add customer DOB field in newsletter subscription form.And it should be the dropdown of Month Date Year.

Can anyone help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your newsletter.phtml file

```
        <li class="control">

        <?php echo "Date Of Birth". $this->getDateBirth(); ?>    
        <p>Select date:</p>
        <select name="day" style="width: 50px;">
        <?php
        for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
        {
            echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
        }?>
        </select>

        <select name="month" style="width: 50px;">
        <option value="01">January</option>
        <option value="02">February</option>
        <option value="03">Mars</option>
        <option value="04">April</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">June</option>
        <option value="07">July</option>
        <option value="08">August</option>
        <option value="09">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>

        <select name="year" style="width: 50px;">
        <?php
        for($i=1950;$i<=2014;$i++)
        {
            echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
        }

        ?>
        </select>
        </li>
```

In your newsletter module controller file ManageController.php (default file) need to override function saveAction() with below changes 
add below code in try section

```
        $day = $this->getRequest()->getParam('day', false);
        $month = $this->getRequest()->getParam('month', false);
        $year = $this->getRequest()->getParam('year', false);
        $buildDateofBirth = $year."-".$month."-".$day." 00:00:00";
        $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        if ($customerData->getId()) {
           $customerData->setDob($buildDateofBirth)->save(); 
        }
```

You are done. hope this helps...